# Escribir/Leer estructuras en archivos binarios

Tags: c

Creo que estoy haciendo un mal uso de los punteros al leer o escribir mi código ya que solo recibo NULL.

Al usar fwrite no se si debo pasar solo mi arreglo o el puntero del arreglo para poder leerlo despues correctamente

Este es mi archivo para escribir:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct Empleado
{
  char nombre[20];
  int edad;
  float sueldo;
};

int main (){    
    int num_emp=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    FILE *archivo2; 


    printf("Ingrese el numero de empleados a capturar\n");
    scanf("%d",&num_emp);
    fflush(stdin);
    struct Empleado **empleados = (struct Empleado **)calloc(num_emp,sizeof(struct Empleado*));

    for(i=0;i<num_emp;i++){
        struct Empleado *emp = (struct Empleado *)malloc(sizeof(struct Empleado));
        printf("Nombre del empleado: ");
        scanf("%s",(emp->nombre));
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Edad: ");
        scanf("%i",&(emp->edad));
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Sueldo: ");
        scanf("%f",&(emp->sueldo));
        fflush(stdin);
        empleados[i] = emp;
        printf("\n");
    }
    archivo2=fopen("empleados2.bin","wb");

    if(archivo2 == NULL)
      {
      printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
      return 0;
      }else{        


        fwrite(empleados,sizeof(struct Empleado),num_emp,archivo2);  

fclose(archivo2);


    printf("Se ha generado el archivo Binario \n");  



return 0;
}
}
```

Este es el archivo para leer(otro programa distinto, no en el mismo codigo para escribir):
Tambien mi problema es con la funcion fread, no se si estoy leyendo la variable correcta o debo declararla de otro tipo ya que en mi salida el nombre me sale Null, edad 0 y salario 0.000. Solo estoy tratanto de imprimir el primer elemento por el momento ya cuando funcione podré imprimir los demas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Empleado
{  char nombre[20];
  int edad;
 float sueldo;
};


int main(){

    int num_emp=2;
    FILE *archivo_lectura;

    struct Empleado *emp = (struct Empleado *) malloc (sizeof(struct Empleado));
    struct Empleado **empleados = (struct Empleado **)calloc(num_emp,sizeof(struct Empleado*));


    archivo_lectura = fopen("empleados2.bin","rb+");
    if(archivo_lectura == NULL)
      {
      printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
      return 0;
      }else{


    fread(*empleados,sizeof(struct Empleado),2,archivo_lectura);
    emp=empleados;

    printf("Nombre: %s\t Edad: %d \t Salario: %f",emp->nombre,emp->edad,emp->sueldo);

    fclose(archivo_lectura);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veamos cuales son los parámetros de la función [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/):

- `ptr`: Un puntero que apunta a un *array* de elementos.
- `size`: El tamaño en bytes de cada elemento.
- `count`: El número de elementos que se va a escribir.
- `stream`: Un puntero que apunta a un objeto de tipo `FILE`.

Sabiendo lo anterior, miremos como usas la función `fwrite`:

```c
fwrite(empleados,sizeof(structEmpleado),num_emp,archivo2);
```

Básicamente con ese código lo que estás escribiendo es el contenido del *array* de punteros, pero en ese *array* no es donde tenemos los datos de cada empleado.

Cada **elemento** del *array* de punteros apunta a un objeto de tipo `Empleado` y ahí es donde están los datos. Sin embargo, para lograr esto debemos ir escribiendo en el archivo a través de un bucle:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < num_emp; i++)
    fwrite(empleados[i], sizeof(struct Empleado), 1, archivo2);
```

Los parámetros que pasamos son:

- `empleados[i]`: Nos genera la dirección base del objeto donde están los datos.
- `sizeof(struct Empleado)`: El tamaño que ocupa el objeto.
- `1`: En este caso solo queremos escribir un elemento.

De este modo, escribimos los datos en el archivo exitosamente.

Para leer el archivo lo debemos hacer de esta forma:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < num_emp; i++)
{
        emp = (struct Empleado *) malloc (sizeof(struct Empleado));
        fread(emp, sizeof(struct Empleado), 1, archivo_lectura);
        printf("Nombre: %s\t Edad: %d \t Salario: %f",emp->nombre,emp->edad,emp->sueldo);
        empleados[i] = emp;
}
```

En cada iteración reservamos memoria para un objeto de tipo `Empleado` y almacenamos la dirección base en el puntero `emp` y posteriormente, le pasas dicha dirección al primer parámetro de la función `fread`. Esta rutina se encargará de leer cada bloque de memoria donde estén los datos del archivo y los copiará en nuestra memoria que reservamos con `malloc`. Y al final, guardamos la dirección base en `X` posición del *array* de punteros.

También debemos liberar la memoria cuando ya no sea necesaria:

```c
for(int i = 0; i != num_emp; ++i)
    free(empleados[i]);
free(empleados);
```

**Código completo:**

```c
int escribir ()
{    
    int num_emp=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    FILE *archivo2; 
    printf("Ingrese el numero de empleados a capturar\n");
    scanf("%d",&num_emp);
    fflush(stdin);
    struct Empleado **empleados = (struct Empleado **)calloc(num_emp,sizeof(struct Empleado*));

    for(i=0;i<num_emp;i++)
    {
        struct Empleado *emp = (struct Empleado *)malloc(sizeof(struct Empleado));
        printf("Nombre del empleado: ");
        scanf("%s",(emp->nombre));
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Edad: ");
        scanf("%i",&(emp->edad));
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Sueldo: ");
        scanf("%f",&(emp->sueldo));
        fflush(stdin);
        empleados[i] = emp;
        printf("\n");
    }
    archivo2=fopen("empleados2.bin","wb");

    if(archivo2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {        
        for(int i = 0; i < num_emp; i++)
            fwrite(empleados[i], sizeof(struct Empleado), 1, archivo2);  

        fclose(archivo2);
    }

    printf("Se ha generado el archivo Binario \n");  

    return 0;
}

int leer()
{
    int num_emp = 2;
    FILE *archivo_lectura;
    struct Empleado *emp;
    struct Empleado **empleados = (struct Empleado **)calloc(num_emp,sizeof(struct Empleado*));
    archivo_lectura = fopen("empleados2.bin","rb+");
    if(archivo_lectura == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < num_emp; i++)
        {
            emp = (struct Empleado *) malloc (sizeof(struct Empleado));
            fread(emp, sizeof(struct Empleado), 1, archivo_lectura);
            printf("Nombre: %s\t Edad: %d \t Salario: %f",emp->nombre,emp->edad,emp->sueldo);
            empleados[i] = emp;
        }
        fclose(archivo_lectura);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i != num_emp; ++i)
    {
        emp = empleados[i];
        printf("Nombre: %s\t Edad: %d \t Salario: %f\n", emp->nombre, emp->edad, emp->sueldo);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i != num_emp; ++i)
        free(empleados[i]);
    free(empleados);
}

int main(void)
{
    escribir();
    leer();
    return 0;
}
```

Lo he puesto en dos funciones, ya que de esa forma lo probé.

**Recomendación:**

Te has complicado demasiado. En vez de reservar memoria para un *array* de punteros, hubiese reservado directamente un *array* de estructuras (internamente toda la memoria es contigua).

**Ejemplo:**

```c
void escribir ()
{    
    int num_emp=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    FILE *archivo2; 
    printf("Ingrese el numero de empleados a capturar\n");
    scanf("%d",&num_emp);
    fflush(stdin);
    /* Reservamos memoria para un array de estructuras */
    struct Empleado *emp = calloc(num_emp, sizeof(struct Empleado));

    for(i=0;i<num_emp;i++)
    {
        printf("Nombre del empleado: ");
        scanf("%s", emp[i].nombre);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Edad: ");
        scanf("%i",&emp[i].edad);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Sueldo: ");
        scanf("%f",&emp[i].sueldo);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }
    archivo2=fopen("empleados2.bin","wb");

    if(archivo2 == NULL)
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
    else
    {        
        /* Escribimos los datos del array de estructuras en el archivo */
        fwrite(emp, sizeof(struct Empleado), num_emp, archivo2);  
        fclose(archivo2);
    }
    printf("Se ha generado el archivo Binario \n");  
}

void leer()
{
    int num_emp = 2;
    FILE *archivo_lectura;
    /* Reservamos memoria para un array de estructuras */
    struct Empleado *emp = calloc(num_emp, sizeof(struct Empleado));
    archivo_lectura = fopen("empleados2.bin","rb+");
    if(archivo_lectura == NULL)
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo");
    else
    {
        /* Leemos los datos del fichero y lo guardamos en un array de estructuras */
        fread(emp, sizeof(struct Empleado), num_emp, archivo_lectura);
        for(int i = 0; i != num_emp; ++i)
            printf("Nombre: %s\t Edad: %d \t Salario: %f\n", emp[i].nombre,emp[i].edad,emp[i].sueldo);
        fclose(archivo_lectura);
    }
}
```